# Pass parameter to function interactively

Tags: vim

Right now I'm using vim on mac. How would I input a paramter when I run the file?

```
    def isPositive(num1):
        pos = False
        if num1 > 0:
           pos = True
           return pos
        else:
           pos = False
           return pos
```

Comment: Do you know about the `input` function for interactive input? https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input. If you want to pass arguments to the module, then look at the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module

Comment: If that's all your file, this is just a function definition. Nothing will happen anyway... You need to call it somehow. And as to the parameter, as said in other comments you can either use `input()`, `argparse` or maybe [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
number = input("Enter a number: ")
number = int(number)

def isPositive(num1):
    pos = False
    if num1 > 0:
       pos = True
       return pos
    else:
       pos = False
       return pos

isPositive(number)
```

The input command allows you to enter a string when you run the file. The second line converts that variable to an integer so it can be used in the if statement inside the function. Then at the bottom, the function is called with number as its parameter.